# Javascript - run exe in a New process

Tags: javascript, shell

When I use shell.Run or ShellExecute function it opens my exe, but the exe is not running in a new process.
How can I make it run in a new process?

**EDIT:**
This  is my scenario: I have a website installed on iis on server1. I have 10 citrix clients connecting to this server.
I want, when the user press a button on the asp page, to open a exe in a new process that will run on the citrix client. Not on server1.

Thanks.

Comment: unless your goal is to maliciously infect peoples computers with malware you are using the wrong tool for the job. Client side JS is sandboxed to prevent exactly this kind of thing

Comment: I see what you are saying. I will now edit my question and will explain the whole senario.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "start calc.exe", e.g. That spawns the application in a new process. Additional info can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: i can do it from javascript?\

Comment: You are talking of server-side Javascript, of course? You can't run programs from client-side JS as it is sandboxed in your browser for very good reasons. But you can use it on the backend, with node.js for example: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I'm talking about client side.

Comment: No way. Except perhaps for some disgusting ActiveX adventures with Windows Scripting, but that's neither safe nor elegant and only works for IE in Windows environments. That kind of stuff makes me throw up ;-) Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186813/how-to-run-cmd-exe-with-parameters-from-javascript